# Mac os 10.11.1 MakeFile erro: ext/numeric file not found

Tags: macos, makefile

I am trying to compile a public software called CofiRank. Here is the link to package: https://github.com/markusweimer/cofirank

To compile it I run:

`make -f CofiRank-Makefile.mk CONF=Deploy`

and here is part of my terminal results:

```
g++ -D NDEBUG   -c -g -Isrc -Ilibs -o build/Deploy/GNU-
MacOSX/src/loss/ndcgdomainmodel.o src/loss/ndcgdomainmodel.cpp
In file included from src/utils/ublastools.cpp:1:
src/utils/ublastools.hpp:17:10: fatal error: 'ext/numeric' file not found
#include <ext/numeric>         // for iota
In file included from src/bmrm/solver/dualinnersolver.cpp:29:
src/utils/ublastools.hpp:17:10: fatal error: 'ext/numeric' file not found
#include <ext/numeric>         // for iota
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [build/Deploy/GNU-MacOSX/src/utils/ublastools.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [build/Deploy/GNU-MacOSX/src/bmrm/solver/dualinnersolver.o] 
In file included from src/bmrm/solver/daifletcherpgm.cpp:28:
In file included from src/bmrm/solver/daifletcherpgm.hpp:22:
In file included from src/bmrm/solver/dualinnersolver.hpp:6:
src/utils/ublastools.hpp:17:10: fatal error: 'ext/numeric' file not found
#include <ext/numeric>         // for iota
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [build/Deploy/GNU-MacOSX/src/loss/ndcgdomainmodel.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

I searched a lot but could not fix it. I think I need to use libstd++ instead lib++ which is the default of mac os, but I don't know how to (or if it is the problem)

can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

`<ext/numeric>` is a non-standard header file provided by the GNU C++ standard library (libstdc++) that comes with GCC.

You are probably compiling with Clang, and so need to tell it to use the GNU library not its own one, so compile with `-stdlib=libstdc++`

Comment: how do I do it,
make -f CofiRank-Makefile.mk CONF=Deploy -stdlib=libstdc++
, doesn't work

Comment: It depends on the makefile. Try `make -f CofiRank-Makefile.mk CONF=Deploy CXXFLAGS=-stdlib=libstdc++`

Comment: Then it gives me this error:
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Then you need to add it to whatever variable is used for linking. Maybe try adding `LDFLAGS=-stdlib=libstdc++` as well.

Comment: Still doesn't work. How can I know what the variable is ?

Comment: Look at the makefile. If you're still getting some new error edit your question to show it, so people don't have to guess what the problem is.